# Finding keywords in a set of small texts

Tags: algorithm, keyword, information-retrieval

I have a set of almost 2000 texts.
My goal is to find the keywords across these texts to understand what is the subject of them, or simply the most common words and expressions.

I would like some ideias of algorithms to **score the words** and identify **when they frequently come together**.

I have read some other related questions here, but I'm  trying to get more and more information about this subject. So any ideas are very welcome. Thank you so much!

--

I have already extracted stopwords. After removing them I have more than 7000 words remaing; My question is how to score these words and from which point I can consider removing some them from my list of keywords. Also, how to get key expressions, find words that come together.

Comment: [TF-IDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) is a starter

Answer (score 0):

You may want to refer to a classical text on Information Retrieval.  Most of the algorithms use a *stop list* to remove commonly occurring words such as "for" and "the", and then, extract the base or root word (change "seeing", "seen", "see", "sees" to the base word "see").  The remaining words form the keywords of the document and are weighted by things like term frequency (how many times the word occurs in the document) and inverse document frequency (how unique is the word in describing the content).  You can use the weighted keywords as document representation and use them for retrieval.

Comment: I have already extracted stopwords. After removing them I have more than 7000 words remaing; My question is how to score these words and from which point I can consider removing some them from my list of keywords. Also, how to get key expressions, find words that come together.

Comment: You will have to use some probabilistic techniques to achieve that.  You are better off referring to an IR book for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Lucene *MoreLikeThis* implementation, which extracts a list of top most important keywords from a given text document. The term scoring function it uses is the tf-idf, i.e. it chooses those terms with topmost tf-idf scores, i.e. the terms which are relatively uncommon and occur frequently in the document.
If efficiency is an issue, it employs some common heuristics as follows.

Since you're trying to maximize a tf*idf score, you're probably most interested in terms with a high tf. Choosing a tf threshold even as low as two or three will radically reduce the number of terms under consideration.  Another heuristic is that terms with a high idf (i.e., a low df) tend to be longer.  So you could threshold the terms by the number of characters, not selecting anything less than, e.g., six or seven characters. With these sorts of heuristics you can usually find small set of, e.g., ten or fewer terms that do a pretty good job of characterizing a document.

More details can be found in this [javadoc](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/api/contrib-queries/org/apache/lucene/search/similar/MoreLikeThis.html).